# Problem using EF Core 6 Cosmos DB to make a query using inside the predicate with a Count of a list inside the entity

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-6.0

Considering this simple model, I want to recover using EF Core 6 Cosmos the customers which has between 4 and 6 orders.

```
public class CustomerEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}

public class Order: 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public double TotalDiscount { get; set; }
}
```

For this case, I try to do the next Linq expression using the `DbContext`:

```
dbContext.Customers
         .Where(c => c.Orders.Count >= 4 && c.Orders.Count <= 6)
         .Count()
```

This code causes an exception in my application:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GetStreams. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: The LINQ expression 'DbSet() [2023-03-31T08:25:24.420Z]     .Where(EF.Property<IList>(s, "Order") [2023-03-31T08:25:24.421Z]         .AsQueryable() [2023-03-31T08:25:24.423Z]         .Count() >= __get_Item_0 && EF.Property<IList>(s, "Order") [2023-03-31T08:25:24.424Z]         .AsQueryable() [2023-03-31T08:25:24.424Z]         .Count() <= __get_Item_1 && True && True && True)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I tried another solution, like using a `SELECT`, `WHERE` apply again the `Count` in this order.

I saw too that there is a new version of EF Core Cosmos 7 but in my case I can't use it in a Azure Functions because of a incompatibility between both, I think.

Comment: Azure functions support .NET 6 [Azure Functions 4.0 and .NET 6 support are now generally available](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-functions-4-0-and-net-6-support-are-now-generally/ba-p/2933245). EF Core 7 is targeted to .NET 6.

Comment: @Jorge Lopez can you please try `dbContext.Customers.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Orders != null && c.Orders.Count >= 2 && c.Orders.Count <= 3).Count();` and check whether its working.

Comment: @RitikaNalwaya Yes, with that approuch it is working, but the problem is about the filter is not happening inside a cosmos db query, it is performed in memory and cpu, so if you have a lot of entities it will be slow.